# Compiling a project gives failed processing manifest

Tags: android, gradle

I'm writing an android application in android studio. I've copied all my files into my laptop and tried to code at my laptop. But it gives error. Same code and project works fine at my office. Everything is same even plugins and android studio version and sdks.

```
 Android resource linking failed
 Output:  error: failed to create directory 'D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\com\proj\myAndroidProject'.
 error: failed processing manifest.

 Command: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\59ab4fa63f718f7aea51e7b0302c53bc\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
    D:\AndroidSdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
    --manifest\
    D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\merged_manıfests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
    -o\
    D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
    -R\
    @D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
    --auto-add-overlay\
    --java\
    D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
    --proguard-main-dex\
    D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multıdex_aapt_derıved_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
    --custom-package\
    com.proj.myAndroidProject\
    -0\
    apk\
    --output-text-symbols\
    D:\myAndroidProject\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
    --no-version-vectors
 Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: Just clean the project and build again hope will be solve

Comment: nope, i tried that. Invalidate cache, clean etc. nothing seems works. I cant solve :(

Comment: delete all folders from build and then make build

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before. This problem was caused when I copied classes or changed their name.

If you also have this problem, it's because of unwittingly some files that are normally unaddressed.

It is best to create classes and projects first, then copy their content or create .jar libraries and add them to your project.

Try to uninstall android studio once and reinstall and get full Internet access and if app need update it .

If error not resolved , you can turn off debuger in your project.

I hope you help.